# Flutter: How to pop last visited screen from stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

Let say i have three screens: `wallet`, `payments`, `add card`. I want to pop `payments` screen from stack when i'm on `add card` screen and navigate it to `wallet` screen without using `navigator.push` on click on icon plus the back icon of device.

here is the flow of screen:

`wallet` screen has a button which navigate to the `payments` screen, then `payments` screen has a button which navigate to the `add card` screen . So, now i want when i am on `add card` screen and click on back icon of android or the icon which is on `add card` screen both should navigate to `wallet` screen.

Please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question how your navigation stack should look: Is `payments` first in the stack, and can you go from there to `add card` and `wallet`? Or should only one exist?

I think you can use `pushReplacement`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html

That way, it'll automatically replace the current route with the new one, and your back button will simply close the app (or go back to the screen before it). If you want some custom behavior when the back button is pressed, you can always use a `WillPopScope`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Comment: my first screen is ```wallet```, there is a button and i'm navigating ```payment``` screen on its click then on payment screen there is a button and on click on it i'm navigating ```add card``` screen. now i want when i go back from ```add card``` screen my last visited screen on stack now is ```payment``` screen i want to pop it and want to display wallet screen but without using ```navigator.push```

Comment: My solution should work then, right? From `payment` you can `pushReplacement` `add card`, so when it's popped again, you don't go to payment, but instead back to wallet immediately. If you don't want to use navigation you can use a single widget with a state that changes to display either the `payment` or `add card` view, within the same route

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigator.removeRoute(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => payments()));
```

use this code when you remove your payments screen

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code

1. PopAndPushNamed ->
   Pop the current route off the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context and push a named route in its place.

It pops payments screen from the navigation stack and only wallet screen remains in Navigation stack

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/addCard');
```

2. PushNamedAndRemoveUntil ->
   It pushes the route with the given name (Wallets) onto the navigator, and then remove all the previous routes until the predicate returns true. Here it is using a RoutePredicate that always returns false (Route route) => false. In this situation it removes all of the routes except for the wallets route pushed.

```
//named
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('\wallets', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    
//not named
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
    Wallets()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
```

3. PopUntil ->
   Calls pop repeatedly on the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context until the predicate returns true.
   The predicate may be applied to the same route more than once if Route.willHandlePopInternally is true.
   To pop until a route with a certain name, use the RoutePredicate returned from ModalRoute.withName.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/wallets'));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacement()
```